# Error BC30560: 'ReportViewer' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms'

Tags: publish, reportviewer

I get this error some 23 times when publishing the website. There are no issues with compilation and testing. I know someone is going to have the urge to say "remove the duplicate reference from the web.config" but that's not the problem here. This is a project started in 2008 and the use of ReportViewer predates the code being added to our git repository (which in turn predated me working on it) so I know that nothing is technically wrong with the code. In fact, until last week, it published just fine. What changed? I finally got a newer, faster computer. The client wanted one line removed. I put the code on the new computer, removed the offending line, built, tested. All is ok. Then I went to publish and got the ReportViewer error. I'm working with a byte-for-byte copy of the project on the old computer and the only thing that fails is the publish on the new computer.

Clearly something isn't installed on the new computer that's preventing publish, but I don't have a clue what it is. (Or possibly something installed that shouldn't be. The "new" computer was actually in-use by another developer.)

Answer (score 0):

I was grasping at anything for this problem. I got the idea to remove all copies of the ReportViewer DLL from the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms folder. There were 5 different versions. Windows itself balked when I tried to move version 10. That was my clue. It turns out that whoever switched from version 10 to version 12 missed a couple of source files. I updated the reference to version 12 and the problems cleared up.

Now the real mystery is: why did it ever work on the old computer?